# Different S3 Buckets to implement Filepicker.io

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, filepicker.io

My app has different buckets for dev, staging, and production, but we're currently looking to implement `Filepicker.io` for media uploads.

Is there any way to change the bucket used for store depending on the rails environment?

Comment: Just realized I can use multiple apps in Filepicker with different buckets set, and change the API key for each app.

Comment: @JellyBeans the formatting you applied to this question is *not* proper. Please do not apply bold highlighting to random words like this.

Comment: Yes, the recommended way to do this is to have a dev, staging, and production Filepicker.io app, and switch between them in your rails config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discovered in the comments, the way to handle this is to have multiple apps in Filepicker for each environment and use the corresponding API key for each in rails config.

Comment: Unfortunately if you rely on paid features this means paying for 2 or 3 separate Filepicker plans.